# Cannot send Github scheduled reminders test

Tags: github, slack

In Github's Slack integration, I would like to receive Slack messages when I am mentioned in Github issues. I set up scheduled reminders and enabled real-time alerts.

When I click the speaker button "Send a test reminder", I see an error

> We tried to send a test message, however you won't receive any
> messages because no matching pull requests were found.

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

I am subscribed to pull requests in the Slack app. I have previously received updates from the Github repo from where I am attempting to send myself a test.

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue ?